# Permission problems in system directories

Tags: 11.10, permissions, system

Please, i am using Ubuntu 11.10 and I made a mistake in system directories, changed permissions of all content to 777. I was trying to correct some files, but i cant fix   all directories and files. Can I return to default permissions??

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you fix file permissions for root directory?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/25590/how-do-you-fix-file-permissions-for-root-directory)

Comment: cant fix from first command:

chown: can not get the target referenced by "/ etc / blkid.tab": File or directory not found

--->> Sorry, not working!

Comment: Which command didn't work? you should be able to use chown

Comment: i am trying: sudo chown root.root /etc/*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
We trust you have received the usual lecture from the local System Administrator. It usually boils down to these three things:

#1) Respect the privacy of others.
#2) Think before you type.
#3) With great power comes great responsibility.
```

fdisk, format, reinstall, doo dah, doo dah. i.e.

```
root@loki:~# find /etc/ -type f -exec ls -al {} \; | awk '{print $1}' | sort | uniq
-r--r-----
-rw-------
-rw-r-----
-rw-r--r--
-rw-rw-r--
-rwxr-xr-x
root@loki:~# find /etc/ -type d -exec ls -al {} \; | awk '{print $1}' | sort | uniq
drwx------
drwxr-s---
drwxr-xr-x
drwx--x---
lrwxrwxrwx
-r--r-----
-rw-------
-rw-r-----
-rw-r--r--
-rw-rw-r--
-rwxr-xr-x
```

some blanket chmod'ing and chowning in /etc is not going to fix this. you've made a proper mess of things, and a reinstall is the quickest and cleanest way to fix it RIGHT. any thing else, short of restoring content or images from backups is both a waste of time and incomplete.

chalk it up to experience (i've certainly hosed many an install learning), and move forward.

Comment: Yes... i have some differences on my permissions... I will reinstall. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Let's do this from the terminal

1) `sudo -i`

2) `sudo chown root.root /etc/*`

3) `sudo chmod 755 /etc/*`

4) exit

In case you need to reset the permissions on sudoers, the permissions should be set to:

1) `chmod 440 /etc/sudoers`

It is owned by root.root

I think most file system have permission of 755 for folders and 644 for files except for /bin which has executable files with root as owner.Hope this helps...

[ref](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=620016)

Comment: Hi, thanks. Same I mentioned above when i using the second command: "chown: can not get the target referenced by "/ etc / blkid.tab": File or directory not found".